# Amazon S3 Java SDK - use https to list buckets

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a common question but I am yet to find an answer. I have a simple code snippet as follows where I am trying to retrieve the list of buckets using HTTPS.

```
    final String username = "username";
    final String password = "password";
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(username,password);

    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
    final String serviceurl = "ip:port";
    s3.setEndpoint(serviceurl);
    S3ClientOptions s3ClientOptions = new S3ClientOptions();
    s3ClientOptions.setPathStyleAccess(true);
    s3.setS3ClientOptions(s3ClientOptions);

    for (Bucket bucket: s3.listBuckets()) {
        System.out.println("Bucket name::" + bucket.getName());
    }
```

When I run this code it gives me an error. Please help.

```
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
    INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
```

Comment: Please post the exact version of the JRE you're running this on. The Oracle JSSE suites are known to have buggy cipher-suite selection configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using java 1.7.0_25.

Comment: The S3 client in the Java SDK will use HTTPS by default. Any particular reason for all of these complications?